# resetting a form using redux-form and immutablejs

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have been trying to get a handle on redux-form and immutablejs and i think i've got most of the pieces down. However, I know I'm missing at least one step. Not all the props that i would expect to be passed to the form component are being passed to it. For example, `formKey` is `undefined`. I noticed this when i went to try to make use of `this.props.resetForm`. The function exists but it doesn't seem to do anything. The form inputs remain changed and `pristine` is false. Here is my form and root reducer:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
export const fields = [ 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email' ]

class ContactForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const {fields: {firstName, lastName, email}} = this.props;
    const handleSubmit = function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('firstName', firstName.value)
    }

    const reset = function () {
      console.log('before', this.props)
      this.props.resetForm()
      console.log('after', this.props)
    }.bind(this)

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="First Name" {...firstName}/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" {...lastName}/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email" {...email}/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <br/><br/>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const ContactFormContainer = reduxForm({ 
  form: 'contact',                           
  fields,
  getFormState: (state, reduxMountPoint) => state.get(reduxMountPoint).toJS()
},
function (state, ownProps) {
    const contact = state.get('contacts').get(ownProps.contactId);
    return {
        initialValues: contact.toJS()
    }
}
)(ContactForm);

export default ContactFormContainer;
```

.

```
import Immutable, {Map, fromJS} from 'immutable'
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux-immutable';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import contacts from './contacts/reducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    form: (state = Immutable.fromJS({}), action) => Immutable.fromJS(formReducer(state.toJS(), action)),  
    contacts
});

const initialState = Map();

export default createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question so I suppose you fixed it by now, but if you still have a problem I would recommend upgrading redux-form library to v6 and checking out example with Immutable.js:

http://redux-form.com/6.0.2/examples/immutable/

This example is using redux-immutablejs library but it should also work with redux-immutable as it says in the example.